# set object is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, set

When I try to run the following code:

```
import json

d = {'testing': {1, 2, 3}}
json_string = json.dumps(d)
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    json_string = json.dumps(d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: set([1, 2, 3]) is not JSON serializable
```

What can I do to successfully use `json.dumps` with objects containing `set`s?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Turn sets into lists before serializing, or use a custom `default` handler to do so:

```
def set_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, set):
        return list(obj)
    raise TypeError

result = json.dumps(yourdata, default=set_default)
```

Comment: json.dumps(yourdata, default=list) also works

Comment: or `d = {'testing': list({1, 2, 3})}`

Answer (score 2):

You can't fix it.

This error means just "json.dumps doesn't support data type "set".You should know JSON comes from javascript. And there is no data type like Python's "set" in javascript. So Python can't treat 'set' using JSON.

So you need another approach like @Martijn Pieters mentioned.

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot to say this.

If you want to dump "set" or any other python object that is not supported JSON, you can use `pickle` or `cPickle` module. If you use the "dump.txt" only from Python, this may be helpful.

```
import cPickle

d = {'testing': {1, 2, 3}}

#dump
with open("pickledump.txt", "w") as fp:
    cPickle.dump(d, fp)

#load
with open("pickledump.txt", "r") as fp:
    x = cPickle.load(fp)
```

Comment: Note my downvote, but I'd hazard a guess the downvote was based on your original post which could be read as: "you can't do that" (which the OP obviously knows as that's what they're asking about) followed by "see Martijn's answer".

Comment: Yes...you're right. What I should say is "You need another approach, because you can't store Python's 'set' as json format."