# how to call python script from R with arguments

Tags: python, r

I have a python script which takes some 5 arguments( a filename, 3 int values and 2 float values). I need to call this python script from R. How can I do that. I am trying to use rPython, but it doesnt allow me to pass the argument

```
library("rPython")
python.load("python scriptname")
```

I dont know how to pass the arguments

from command line, i run my python script like:

```
python scriptname filename 10 20 0.1 5000 30
```

Comment: What does `example(python.load)` or `?python.load` tell you?

Comment: Check if this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667328/error-in-running-a-python-code-from-r-with-the-package-rpithon

Comment: The `reticulate` package is a nice alternative to `rPython`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can invoke a system command

```
system('python scriptname')
```

To run the script asynchronously you can set the wait flag to false.

```
system('python scriptname filename 10 20 0.1 5000 30', wait=FALSE)
```

The arguments that get passed as they would in command line. You will have to use sys.argv in the python code to access the variables

```
#test.py
import sys

arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
print arg1, arg2
```

The R command below would output 'hello world'

```
system('python test.py hello world', wait=FALSE)
```

Comment: great. but system commands waits for the python program to get completed. is there any way it wont wait,

Comment: @user1631306 yes, [Documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) is here. add wait=False

Comment: So using this I'd have to manually type in the entire path to a file if I'm passing a text file as an argument. Is there a way to instead give it a variable name that has the path stored in it? This way I can automate my R script for any input text file.

Comment: Never mind, I found the "system2" command in R with a bit of Googling:

https://www.mango-solutions.com/blog/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa

Comment: > system('python --version')
Warning message:
running command 'python --version' had status 127

Comment: `> system(python /Users/jdmoore7/Downloads/hw.py)
Error in system(python/Users/jdmoore7/Downloads/hw.py) : 
  object 'python' not found` I'm finding that R cannot locate python. At least this is my Mac OSX experience.. EDIT: I'm a fool, I didn't pass in the command as a string! It works now.

Answer (score 9):

There is a small typo in the great previous answer. The right code is the following:

```
 system('python test.py hello world', wait = FALSE)
```

where **wait** is **FALSE** (not wait=Flase or wait=False)